# differentiability of the norm of L^1

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $N_1$ denote the natural norm of the functional space $L^1(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is an open domain of $R^n$:
$$
N(y)=\int_\Omega |y(x)| dx
$$

I have the following question regarding $N_1$:

1. Is $N_1$ differentiable in $L^1(\Omega)-(0)$?
2. If yes, is  the differential Lipschitz?

Comment: Can you write a clear definition of $N_1$ please?

Comment: Calculus of Variations depends on the existence of this kind of derivative.

Comment: It is differentiable in all $y$ for which $\{x \in \Omega \mid y(x) = 0\}$ has measure zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. In $L^1(0,2)$, let $f=\chi_{[0,1]}$ and $g=\chi_{[1,2]}$. Then $$||f+hg||=1+|h|.$$

Comment: so it is weakly differentiable (the kind of differentiability we are interested in, in $L^1$)

Comment: @user1952009 I've thought about it for a few minutes, and I have no idea what you mean by saying $N_1$ is weakly differentiable. What do you mean, exactly?

Comment: @user1952009 (Yes, I'm familiar with the usual notion of weak differentiability. That applies in a totally different context: The function $f\in L^1(\Omega)$ is weakly differentiable if etc. Here $N_1:L^1\to\Bbb R$; that other notion makes no sense here. Hence my question about what you mean...)